# How do I unsave an iMessage photo?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, messages

In the Messages app on my iPhone, I tapped on a photo (sent via iMessage) to view it. Then, I tapped on the save icon (a box with a down arrow) in the bottom-right corner of the screen. How do I undo that? In the Photos app, the photo's thumbnail now appears without a chat icon (which looks like  but without the ellipsis) in the bottom-left corner. How do I make it appear again *with* a chat icon? I don't want to delete the photo from my Photos app. I still want to be able to access it from my Photos app. I just want to unsave it, but I don't see an option for that in Messages or Photos.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to accomplish what you're asking. The photos with the message icon are only there as an easy way to find photos you missed. You're not supposed to leave them there indefinitely if you want to keep those photos.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The intended use is that you either want the photo in your photos app or you don't.

Comment: @Ezekiel OK, thank you. Well, I just want to undo the save. I'm concerned that if I save a photo, then it's copied and takes up twice as much of my iPhone's storage. I don't know, but I guess it won't, since I think iPhone uses APFS. Do you know? Also, every photo in Messages doesn't appear in Photos. Why not? I want to be able to control which photos in Messages appear in Photos. If I delete a photo from Messages, does that delete it from Photos, and then it's permanently gone? The Shared with You feature doesn't seem very intuitive or configurable. I guess I'll turn it off for now.

Comment: I know it does use APFS but I'm not 100% sure whether you'll get that benefit in this case. Perhaps, but not guaranteed. I would just focus on saving the ones you want and not saving the ones you don't. If you're running out of space you can delete them from Messages after saving them.